# Code Climate test reporter configuration in codeclimate.yml

Tags: code-climate

The Code Climate [advanced configuration documentation](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/advanced-configuration) covers all configuration except test reporters.

Can the Code Climate test reporters be configured using `codeclimate.yml` or `codeclimate.json` so that configuration can be placed under version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019-10-15, the test reporting configuration for CodeClimate is only controlled by using the web UI. This is from a support call with CodeClimate.